# How to get rid of gaps around my hyperlink menu in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a school project and I'm currently working on the homepage but I'm not sure how to get rid of the gap that around the edge of my hyper link menu.
[picture of my current homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaXpU.png)
This the code I have for the hyperlink menu.

```
<style>
         nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-color: #cddc39;
            color: #333333;
            margin: 0;
         }
        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
         }
</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Anpost.html">An Post </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Ryanair.html">Ryanair </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Services.html">Services </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Contact.html">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I don't have much experience using HTML so any help would be appreciated.

This the code I have for the hyperlink menu.

```
<style>
         nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-color: #cddc39;
            color: #333333;
            margin: 0;
         }
        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
         }

</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Anpost.html">An Post </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Ryanair.html">Ryanair </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Services.html">Services </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Contact.html">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use space-around apply it to the ul element.  If you want to remove the edge set margin on body to 0.

```css
nav ul {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-color: #cddc39;
            color: #333333;
            margin: 0;
         }
        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
         }
         
body{
background-color:lightblue;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Anpost.html">An Post </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Ryanair.html">Ryanair </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Services.html">Services </a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="Contact.html">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked thanks. It took me a second to realize I had `padding: 5px;` in the body element.